# Save NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I need to save a `NSMutableArray` to `NSUserDefaults`.

I have tried this, but the load method returns a `nil` `NSMutableArray` :

```
//    NSMutableArray *listaAenviar = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 -(void) saveArray {
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[_listaAenviar addObject:@"1"];
[currentDefaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[_listaAenviar mutableCopy]] forKey:@"listaAenviar"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
 } 

 -(void) loadArray {
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
_listaAenviar = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"listaAenviar"];
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using these methods to save an array, a lot easier.

```
-(void)saveData :(NSMutableArray *)dataArray
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the data file
   NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
                                                      stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:
     dataArray toFile:dataFilePath];
}


-(NSMutableArray *)loadData
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the data file
    NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
                                                      stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

    // Check if the file already exists
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dataFilePath])
    {
        NSMutableArray *dataArray;

        dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver
                     unarchiveObjectWithFile: dataFilePath];

        return dataArray;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: work this method if I add a custom object into the NSMutableArray?

Comment: Yes, arrays can store objects of any kind, so it doesn't matter what object is being stored

Comment: @illDev as i know, if you have custom objects then you have to implement encodeWithCoder:coder and initWithCoder:coder in methods in your custom object.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer. This was very helpful.